# MultiMarkdown to HTML in iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, markdown

I am looking for a library that would convert Multimarkdown text to HTML. Is there any option available?

A javascript parser would be better I think.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with MMD is that it is a C library. So it would be difficult to translate this into a JS library that would work in a browser.